# What to do with jqPlot memory leak?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory, memory-leaks, graph

I have heard from too many people that JavaScript libruaries like jqPlot or Flot that are designed to draw graphs have memory leaks if updated live for a long period of time. I know that most use the replot() function to update the graph in real time but that's where the problem seems to happen.

Has anybody figured out a work around this? Maybe refreshing the entire graph and the jquery code in a DIV?

Answer (score 6):

you should use the “destroy” method `(plot.destroy())` on your plot before you empty the container and draw the plot again.
It worked for me!

Comment: I cant figure out how to apply this. Can you give a code example?

Comment: I am in the same boat as Kjensen. Every time I try to call this function I get the error "No data specified."

Answer (score 0):

No, i tried it with emptying the div and redraw the complete diagram with jqPlot. That doesn't help either.
I did it like this:

```js
$('#diagramContainer').empty();
targetPlot = $.jqplot('#diagramContainer',
    toDraw, diagramOptions);
```

Doing this lots of times with many data leads also to memory leaks.